# Formula 4.224 (9) from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (7ed, 2007)

Tags: calculus, integration

Formula 4.224 (9) from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (7ed, 2007) states that
$$\int_0^\pi \ln (a + b\,\cos x)\,dx = π\,\ln \left(\frac{a +\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{2}\right), \quad [a ≥ |b| > 0]$$
Could someone help me to understand how they got to the right-hand side expression?
Thanks!!

Ps: I've found this similar topic that may be helpful:
[A question in Complex Analysis $\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-2r\cos x +r^2)\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352046/a-question-in-complex-analysis-int-02-pi-log1-2r-cos-x-r2-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $f(a) = \displaystyle\int_0^\pi \ln(a + b \cos(x)) d x$, then
\begin{equation}
f'(a) = \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{a + b \cos x} dx = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}
\end{equation}
according to 
[Integrating $\dfrac{1}{a+b\cos(x)}$ using $e^{ix}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469375/integrating-dfrac1ab-cosx-using-eix/3469638#3469638)

Comment: Thanks!! This solves my problem :D